# www. redirect is failing with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress site running on Ubuntu with apache2 server.
I want the server to redirect all traffic from www.mysite.com to mysite.com.

I made the modification in .htaccess file to look like this:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
```

And I modified apache2.conf  to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Still no success.I still get the Ubuntu apache server default page for www.mysite.com. What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77911/discussion-on-question-by-jasond-www-redirect-is-failing-with-htaccess).